# Is it normal for a package to put a file in sudoers.d?

Tags: permissions

In **/etc/sudoers.d**, I found a file named "nova-common".

```
-r--r----- 1 root root  77 Mar 11  2015 nova-common
```

File contents:

```
nova ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/nova-rootwrap /etc/nova/rootwrap.conf *
```

So I looked for the package. Output of **dpkg-query -l nova-common**

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
ii  nova-common    2014.1.3-11  all          OpenStack Compute - common files
```

So I look up the file list of the package on Debian:

```
...
/etc/sudoers.d/nova-common
...
```

So from a security perspective, my question: is it normal/safe for there to be files like this in **/etc/sudoers.d**?

Comment: Would you be alarmed it a package installed an executable setuid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenStack `nova` is the part of OpenStack that handles the provisioning of virtual servers, i.e. a lot of configuration that normally requires root-level access. If you want to automate that, you need some mechanism to grant your automation the necessary rights to carry out the tasks you wish to automate.

You might want to read [the documentation on rootwrap](https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/Rootwrap): it is effectively a mechanism that extends `sudo` with a mechanism that allows the complex filtering of not only commands but their parameters too. So it can, in theory, be much more fine-grained than `sudo` alone.

This should be much more audit-friendy way to add selective permissions to automation than just planting an opaque binary with setuid permissions to the system that needs to be managed.